# Apache - Give Access to /var/log/ folder Only Outside the Document Root ? (Centos Based)

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

My Web server is running on Apache and I have restricted the Apache user not to allow anything outside the **Website Document Root**, However, I need to write a log file (User Auth Log) which needs to be written into a folder of the "***/var/log/app***"

How do I achieve this task in Centos7? Should I use a symlink? if so Can that be secure enough? because this log file will contain very sensitive data about the users, so I don't want to give full entire access to Apache user(only write permission), AND I don't want to keep it in a folder that is in the Document Root as well?

What is the best solution for this type of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Create `/var/log/app/`.

Then modify the permissions so that the Apache user can only write to directory:

`chown -R apache:apache /var/log/app/`

`chmod -R 330 /var/log/app/`

With this configuration only `root`, `apache` and `sudo` privileged users can **write** to the folder.

And only `root` and `sudo` privileged users and **read** the logs.

This way, if the Apache service becomes compromised, the attacker will not be able to read the sensitive logs without performing some kind of privilege escalation attack.

Comment: You also need to set an appropriate SELinux context.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yeah I tried this solution, i think the issue is the SELinux, do you have any solutions or reference how i can allow this in SELinux?